# I get an error message with type match error

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub copydata()
    A = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To A
        If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a20:a25") Then
            Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
            b = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If  
    Next

End Sub
```

I think there something wrong with my value set and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your data set - your `If` statement on line 5 is comparing a single cell's value to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare a single cell to a range directly. Use the worksheet's MATCH to find a value within another range instead.

```
Sub copydata()

    dim i as long, b as long

    with Worksheets("sheet1")

        For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If not iserror(application.match(.Cells(i, "B").Value, .Range("a20:a25"), 0)) Then
                b = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                .Rows(i).Copy destination:=Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(b + 1, "A")
            End If  
        Next

    end with

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This one worked. Thank you THank you thank you

Answer (score 2):

The issue your having appears to be related to the following line:

```
If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a20:a25")
```

In plain English my understanding of what you're trying to do here is check if the value of cell(i,2) is equal to the sum of Range("a20:a25"), do something.

However your problem is that you're essentially checking if a cell value is equal to a worksheet object (the worksheet and range). You've never actually transformed the worksheet object in anyway that would allow you to compare to the value of cell(i,2)

I put together a quick solution with the assumption that you're trying to compare the sum.

```
Sub copydata()

Dim If_Check_Range As Range
Dim Sum_If_Check_Range As Integer

Set If_Check_Range = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a20:a25")

Sum_If_Check_Range = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(If_Check_Range)

A = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To A
    If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = Sum_If_Check_Range Then
        Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(i).Copy Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
        b = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

If you're trying to compare your cell value to EACH item in the range then we'll have to take a different approach, feel free to let me know and I'd be happy to help.

One side note on your code is that I'd recommend always putting Option Explicit at the top of your code. This is good practice as it will always require you to define your variables and help prevent these types of mix-ups.

Given that in this case you weren't comparing variables it may not have helped this time, but it definitely will at other times.

Comment: hi thank you so much first of all. However i wasnt trying to sum the range. i want to macro to match the data in range(a20 to a25) if there is match copy the entire row into next page. i tried your code. it gave me compile error: variable not defined. what should i do??